# Section title in SectionedTableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.5

Im creating a Sectioned tableView and I need to set titles programmatically.But the titles are not static.I want to display date and day which are again not static as title for a particular section.I have both of them  stored in NSString.

In one context like for one company I have  to display like this :

```
1/12/2013 Saturday                        //section 0
13:00hrs  14:00hrs  15:00hrs

1/13/2013 Sunday                          //section 1
14:00hrs  15:00 hrs
```

For another company I have to display like this:

```
1/15/2013 Tuesday                        //section 0
13:00hrs  14:00hrs  15:00hrs

1/16/2013 Wednesday                      //section 1
14:00hrs  15:00 hrs

1/17/2013 Thursday                       //section 2
14:00hrs  15:00 hrs
```

Like this but here I dont have static number of companies and static dates and days.
 Im checking for a particular condition and displaying in sections for particular dates and days.And I have to set title as date and day of that section.

How can I do it?

The calculation of date and day goes like this:

```
-(void)LoadData
{

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [offsetComponents setDay:i];
        NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate: [NSDate date]options:0];
        [offsetComponents release];
        [gregorian release];


        NSDateFormatter *formatterforGridSectionDate=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
         formatterforGridSectionDate.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
        getDateinGridSection=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatterforGridSectionDate stringFromDate:nextDate]] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
        gridSectionDate=[[getDateinGridSection valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@",gridSectionDate); // Here I get date in MM/dd/yyyy format 
        weekdayString=[nextDate descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%A" timeZone:nil locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryRepresentation]];
        NSLog(@"Day :%@",weekdayString);
        [self check];


    }
      //creating a tableView 


}

-(void)check
{
 //calling the service url for the particular day and date and store the values in array
        NSLog(@"%@",array);

        if([array count]>0)
       {
          [tblViewarray addObject:array];

       }
}
```

How can I get the date and day as title for which section is loaded in tableview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Here your requirement is display the date with day name on every section of `UITableView`.

You have array of Dates for example with name **yourDateArray**, here i create code for how to display that date on every section with your required date format.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [yourDateArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{


    NSString *str = [yourDateArray objectAtIndex:section];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy EEEE"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);

    return convertedString;
}
```

Comment: CanI know what is schedules?

Comment: @Sindhia here i update answer and here you can use array instead of NSMutableDictionary with name schedules.. schedules is NSMutableDictionary

Comment: What Im thinking is to add date and day everytime to NSMutableArray as one object and use that array in titleForHeaderInSection.But I couldnot understand how can I add two items (date and day ) as one object to NSMutableArray.Can u please tell me how ?

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I add two strings as one object at a particular  index in NSMutableArray?I mean like adding [array addObject:gridSectionDate,weekdayString];But I m getting error.

Comment: hey you can add object with key in dictinaory like NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dict setObject:something forKey:@"Some Key"];

Comment: @Sindhia here why you want this different value with date and also day  you can store it with one object not with different key this is one value like.. 1/12/2013 Saturday

Comment: here you said "I add two items (date and day )" but here why you want to add this different way to store you can get day from only date so dont try add these two item differently .. so please just try to add it in array and direct use with objectAtIndex property of NSMutable array.,...

Comment: yes when im adding like this    [dict setObject:gridSectionDate forKey:@"Date"];
        [dict setObject:weekdayString forKey:@"Date"];
        
        [arrayforGridDateandDay addObject:dict];But im getting only days added and that same days

Comment: or when i add like this :[array addObject:date,day]; Im getting error expected 1 have 2.Where I m going wrong

Comment: @Sindhia just add date in array now after i also give you code which autamatically display with day name...now just add date in that array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22625/discussion-between-sindhia-and-paras-joshi)